# What's the Probability of a drunk man open a door with $n$ possible keys?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions

I have this following problem in my problem set and I would like to check if my work is in the right directio.

> A drunk man with $n$ keys wants to open his door and tries the keys at random. Exactly one key will open the door. Find the mean number of trials if
>
> a) unsuccessful keys are not eliminated from further selections;
>
> b) unsuccsesful keys are eliminated

It seems clear to me that in the first case we have a Geometric distribution with parameter $1/n$, so the expected number of trials is just $n$.

For the second case, my reasoning follows. Let $X$ denote the number of trials until he opens the door.

$P(X = 1) = 1/n$

$P(X = 2) =(n-1)/n \cdot 1/n-1 = 1/n$

$P(X = 3) = (n-1)/n \cdot (n-2)/(n-1) \cdot 1/(n-2) = 1/n$, and so on.

I'm inclined to say that, in the second case, the probabilities over the possible $n$ values of $X$ are uniformly distributed. If this is case, then the average number of trails should be $(n+1)/2$.

Does it seem correct? If not, how to do it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your results are correct. But some calculations  for the expected values would be more convincing.

Comment: Sure, I agree. This was just to check if my reasoning was on the right path, thanks a lot!

Comment: You´re welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Let $X$ be the number of trials. Expectation value $E[X]$ is given by the standard formula:
$$E[X] = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot P(X=k),$$
where $P(X=k)$ is the probability that in the $k$-th trial the guy opened the door.

In the first case, we are returning the key back. If $k$-th trial was successful, then previous $k-1$ should not be. We can write:
$$P(X=k) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{n},$$
and the expectation value is
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} k \left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{k-1} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{[1 - (n-1)/n]^2} = n.$$

In the second case, wrong keys are thrown away. The probability in this case is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=1) & = \frac{1}{n}, \\
P(X=2) & = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}, \\
P(X=3) & = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n-2} = \frac{1}{n}, \\
P(X=k) & = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n-(k-1)}{n-(k-2)} \cdot \frac{1}{n-(k-1)} = \frac{1}{n}, \\
P(X \geqslant n+1) & = 0.
\end{align}
$$
The probability that the guy successfully opens the door after any number of trials is the same. Expectation value equals:
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1+n}{2}n =  \frac{1+n}{2}.$$

Comment: Wrt the expectation value of the first case: Could you explain, how you got from the left term to the right term (eliminating the summation)?

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, let's assume it take $t$ trials. Then we have:

$$t = \frac{1}{n}\cdot 1 + \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot (1 + t)$$

Because there's an $\frac{1}{n}$ chance it only takes $1$ trial and $\frac{n-1}{n}$ chance we didn't make progress at all and still require $t$ trials. Simply solve for $t$.

For the second case, let's assume it takes $t_n$ trials. Then we have:

$$t_1 = 1 \quad  \wedge  \quad t_n = \frac{1}{n}\cdot 1 + \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot (1 + t_{n-1})$$
$$t_n = \frac{n - 1}{n}t_{n-1} + 1$$

Now you conjectured that $t_n = (n+1) / 2$, by induction $t_1$ holds and we have:

$$t_n = (n+1)/2$$
$$t_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}\cdot (n+1)/2 + 1$$
$$t_{n+1} = (n + 2)/2$$

Comment: @orlp Something is not right. From the first equation I get $t=1$.

Comment: @WoofDoggy Fixed, $t$ should be $1 + t$.